# Only rendering a content field if it has a value

Tags: page-layout, site-column

I have a page layout with a field defined like so:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="30809220-9D7B-4124-8672-4DBBCEA8C67D" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
```

Everything is working fine with it.  My question is, how can I only render the field if it has a image/value assigned to it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please be more specific about the problem? Correct me if I'm wrong, if you render the field only if it has some image/value assigned to it then how are you going to set a value in it for the first time? I dont see the 'Value' attribute set in your example.

There's one common problem with this field rendering when you dont have any image in it. You may find solution for that [here](http://www.guilhermemagalhaes.com/?p=53)

Comment: Your link described my problem exactly. The javascript approach to removing the wrapping elements was what I was considering but hoped there was a "cleaner" server-side approach.